# Would PHP cron job cause memory increase in my web server?

Tags: php, memory-leaks

I have a PHP cron job that runs every 15 mins in my VPS server. It makes over 200 http requests and parses/stores data into a local database.

I observed the memory in my VPS server increases slowly & steadily. It was 680M used memory after reboot, and after 1 day, it is now 2.7G used memory.

I am wondering if the PHP cron job causes this memory increase. Isn't PHP a script and when it's finishes, it's like the end of a program and all memory is released?

Can PHP cause memory leak like this? and what to be heeded?

Thanks.

Comment: How long does your script take to run? If it takes more than 15 minutes, then it will overlap with itself and as time goes by, get slower and slower until you have several of those cron scripts running in parallel and each one will take hours (because so many scripts are running), and the problem will continue to get worse.

Comment: Take a look at the process list to see if you have the PHP cron job hanging as a zombie or not completing or whatever.

Comment: It takes about 7-8 mins. From "top", nothing particular happens. No zombie PHP hanging either.

Comment: I have removed the cron job, but the memory still increases. It's very weird. The server had a clean install with cPanel. I didn't add anything to it. It's just a regular web server.

Comment: the second line in "free -m" actually doesn't show the memory increase. I think I looked at the wrong part, which is the cached memory and the increase is normal. So my question becomes invalid.